# Macbook Pro SATA to SSD upgrade with out OSX disc

Tags: ssd, macbook, macbook-pro

Ok just got a SSD and I want to put it into my late-2011 model Macbook Pro. Swapping it out physically isn't the hard part as that's just a handful of screws. It's not having a disc for OSX that's confusing me. I hear there's a second drive in the macs that contain the install, my Mac was bought off the shelf with OSX installed. But all in all I dunno if this is true or not so before I go yanking parts out I wanna make sure I can install the os without a physical copy if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well couldn't find a solid answer anywhere so I gave it a spin with just dropping the new SSD into its place. Turned on the MacBook pro, and held down the option key while crossing my fingers. To my surprise I got a network connection screen which then lead me into the restore and recovery options. After about a 20 or 30 minute download to I guess get the software to do it. Sooo I selected the erase option so I could format the drive, default settings "journaled" for those curious. That finished in about 2 seconds. Then I backed out of that and went to the install/recovery screen where apple verified my Mac, now it's downloading a fresh install for the laptop, kinda lengthy but should be up running and all set in a couple hours..

So in all I answered my own question and for those curious this is your answer.